# Crystal Report asks for database Access login

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

```
    Dim rpt As New stage1
    rpt.Load("stage1.rpt")
    Dim dx As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
    Dim cx As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    For Each dx In rpt.Database.Tables
        cx = dx.LogOnInfo
        cx.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Application.StartupPath & "\studentdb.accdb"
        cx.ConnectionInfo.Password = "19922991"
        dx.ApplyLogOnInfo(cx)
    Next
    reports.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    reports.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    reports.ShowDialog()][1]
```

how to solved error Access database login crystal report vb.net?

Comment: I don't see a username specified --- if you didn't create a specific user/password combination in the database, try the default "Admin" username with your password.

Comment: I use this and the same error
cx.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "Admin"  @Hobbes